# Linux Mint make Kohana's logs and cache writable

Tags: linux, kohana, linux-mint, distro

I can't properly install kohana on my mint distro, because the cache and logs aren't writable. I've tried `chmod 777 cache` and same for logs, but it just won't change. `chmod a+w` didn't help either.

Any solutions?

Comment: Whatever you do, `chmod 777` is certainly wrong -- pretty much regardless of what your problem is. Please help stamp out this voodoo programming antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that you already had some logs which permissions did not change with `chmod`. I would recommend that you try a recursive chmod with `chmod -R 777 cache`. Also, though I am certain that you already checked those things, make sure that these directories truly exist and that they were not misplaced.